C++ Hermite interpolation - Generate coefficients & value
I'm trying to fix my Hermite interpolation program, which is supposed to output the coefficients and value at a point, but it seems the results are wrong. It currently looks like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct DataPoint {
    double x;
    vector<double> values;  
};

void computeDividedDifferences(vector<DataPoint>& points, vector<int>& multiplicity, vector<vector<double>>& divDiff) {
    int n = points.size();
    int totalNodes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        totalNodes += multiplicity[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totalNodes; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalNodes; ++j) {
            divDiff[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < multiplicity[i]; ++k) {
            divDiff[index][0] = points[i].values[k];
            if (k != 0) {
                divDiff[index][1] = points[i].values[k] / k;
            } else if (index != 0) {
                divDiff[index][1] = (divDiff[index][0] - divDiff[index - 1][0]) / (points[i].x - points[(index - 1) / multiplicity[(index - 1) / multiplicity[i]]].x);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 2; j < totalNodes; ++j) {
        for (int i = j; i < totalNodes; ++i) {
            divDiff[i][j] = (divDiff[i][j - 1] - divDiff[i - 1][j - 1]) / (points[i / multiplicity[i / multiplicity[i]]].x - points[(i - j) / multiplicity[(i - j) / multiplicity[i]]].x);
        }
    }
}

double hermitePolynomial(double x, vector<DataPoint>& points, vector<int>& multiplicity, vector<vector<double>>& divDiff) {
    int n = points.size();
    int totalNodes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        totalNodes += multiplicity[i];
    }

    double result = divDiff[0][0];
    double product = 1.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < totalNodes; ++i) {
        product *= (x - points[i / multiplicity[i / multiplicity[i]]].x);
        result += divDiff[i][i] * product;
    }

    return result;
}

void printCoefficients(vector<DataPoint>& points, vector<int>& multiplicity, vector<vector<double>>& divDiff) {
    int n = points.size();
    int totalNodes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        totalNodes += multiplicity[i];
    }

    cout << "Hermite polynomial coefficients:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNodes; ++i) {
        cout << "a" << i << " = " << divDiff[i][i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int k;
    cout << "Enter the number of nodes minus one (k): ";
    cin >> k;
    int n = k + 1;

    vector<DataPoint> points(n);
    vector<int> multiplicity(n);

    cout << "Enter the values of interpolation nodes (x[i], where i = 0, ..., k):" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "x[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> points[i].x;
    }

    cout << "Enter the multiplicities of nodes (m[i], where i = 0, ..., k):" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "m[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> multiplicity[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        points[i].values.resize(multiplicity[i]);
        cout << "Enter the function values and its derivatives at node " << points[i].x << " (f[i][s], where s = 0, ..., m[i] - 1):" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < multiplicity[i]; ++j) {
            cout << "f[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
            cin >> points[i].values[j];
        }
    }

    vector<vector<double>> divDiff(2 * n, vector<double>(2 * n));
    computeDividedDifferences(points, multiplicity, divDiff);

    double x;
    cout << "Enter the value of x to calculate the Hermite polynomial: ";
    cin >> x;

    double result = hermitePolynomial(x, points, multiplicity, divDiff);
    cout << "The value of the Hermite polynomial at point " << x << " is: " << result << endl;

    printCoefficients(points, multiplicity, divDiff);

    return 0;
}

The input i give is:
Enter the number of nodes minus one (k): 2
Enter the values of interpolation nodes (x[i], where i = 0, ..., k):
x[0] = 0
x[1] = 1
x[2] = 2
Enter the multiplicities of nodes (m[i], where i = 0, ..., k):
m[0] = 1
m[1] = 1
m[2] = 2
Enter the function values and its derivatives at node 0 (f[i][s], where s = 0, ..., m[i] - 1):
f[0][0] = 2
Enter the function values and its derivatives at node 1 (f[i][s], where s = 0, ..., m[i] - 1):
f[1][0] = 3
Enter the function values and its derivatives at node 2 (f[i][s], where s = 0, ..., m[i] - 1):
f[2][0] = 4
f[2][1] = 5
Enter the value of x to calculate the Hermite polynomial: 4

the results i get are:
The value of the Hermite polynomial at point 4 is: 3.79421e+99
Hermite polynomial coefficients:
a0 = 2
a1 = 1
a2 = 0
a3 = 1.58092e+98

But the results that another Hermite interpolation calculator I'm trying to recreate gives are
a[0] =  2 
a[1] = -5 
a[2] =  6 
a[3] = -2 
The value of polynomial at  x =  4: 
H(x) =  5.4

I tried to debug it, read more about how Hermite interpolation works and look at the code again, but I'm still not sure what seems to be the problem. I want the code to output correct coefficients and value at a point.

Are you sure this is a Hermite interpolation implementation? How do you calculate the derivatives? I'd post a question here, if I were you.

Some more debugging on your part to narrow down the problem would be helpful. For example, each time you assign a value to divDiff, print that value out as well with something like std::cerr << "divDiff[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " << divDiff[i][j] << "\n"; Compare that to the expected values. Similarly, output product and result each time those are updated. Where do values deviate from expected? You might also want to check each piece of your large expressions. I got a floating point exception when I tried your code and input.
